# Environment variables not set in keycloak started in docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile, environment-variables, keycloak

I'm trying to start keycloak service in docker. I set keycloak environment variables in an `.env` file, and when the container starts, they remain unset. The `.env` file is located in `/opt/keycloak/bin/`. I have a link to it in my `standalone.sh` file. It looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
#source /opt/keycloak/bin/.env

dotenv () {
  set -a
  [ -f ./.env ] && . ./.env
  set +a
}
dotenv
echo $DB_ADDR
# Use --debug to activate debug mode with an optional argument to specify the port.
# Usage : standalone.sh --debug
#         standalone.sh --debug 9797
. . .
```

---

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

ENV KEYCLOAK_HOME /opt/keycloak

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -yq openjdk-8-jdk

RUN apt-get install unzip

COPY ./keycloak.zip /tmp/
RUN unzip /tmp/keycloak.zip -d /opt/ && \
    rm /tmp/keycloak.zip

RUN groupadd --system keycloak && \
    useradd -r -g keycloak -d $KEYCLOAK_HOME -s /sbin/nologin keycloak && \
    chown -RH keycloak: $KEYCLOAK_HOME && \
    chmod +x $KEYCLOAK_HOME/bin/*.sh

COPY ./.env /opt/keycloak/bin/

EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8787

USER keycloak 
WORKDIR $KEYCLOAK_HOME

CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "$KEYCLOAK_HOME/bin/standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0"]
```

my .env file if needed :

```
KEYCLOAK_USER=admin
KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin
KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL=test.ru
KEYCLOAK_STATISTICS=all
PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING="false"
KEYCLOAK_LOGLEVEL=WARN
ROOT_LOGLEVEL=WARN
KEYCLOAK_DEFAULT_THEME=base
DB_VENDOR=postgres
DB_ADDR=172.0.0.1
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=test
DB_USER=test
DB_PASSWORD=test
```

When I start my container, the variables are not set, and I don't know, what's the reason. I will be glad to any advice!

Comment: `CMD /bin/sh -c "dotenv && $KEYCLOAK_HOME/bin/standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0"`

Comment: kampit, thank you for your answer. Could you please tell me the way to install dotenv to my docker image? I try to do it with `apt-get -y install dotenv` command, but the contaainer doesn't start on `CMD /bin/sh -c "dotenv && $KEYCLOAK_HOME/bin/standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0"`. And when I start it without dotenv and try to use dotenv from`docker exec`, I have a `dotenv: not found` error